# Cross platform, open source, console GUI

Tags: c++, console

What would be the best, most portable, simplest way to create a GUI-like feeling in the command line?

Basically I'm asking for a library that allows you to change background and text colors, have a text input area on the bottom of the console, and be able to edit a certain area in the command line without having to clear the whole screen. Does such a library exist?

**Example from IRSSI**

[image: Command line GUI]

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [ncurses](http://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/)

Answer (score 2):

[ncurses](http://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/ncurses.html)?

Here is a HowTo: http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/index.html

Answer (score 1):

[PDCurses](http://pdcurses.sf.net) or ncurses (if you care only about *nixes). irssi uses the latter.

Answer (score 0):

[ncurses](http://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/) ?

Though if you need MS Windows support, you may find limitations.

Answer (score 0):

NCurses always clears the whole screen. Is there any alternative which only changes the colors but not mess with the current console content?

Comment: if you only need colors, then you can simply output the shell escapes characters; although that wouldn't really solve portability.